# How to combine indicators resulting from a machine learning classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

I've done a classification with different machine learning method, as result i've the confusion matrix and the roc curve. To find best classification model, i'm looking for a method to combine the indicators computed with the confusion matrix, for example i've thought :

```
score=efficiency+purity+completeness-contamination
```

or

```
score=(efficiency+purity+completeness)/contamination
```

and then find the model with the max score.
What is the better criterion?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you train a neural network using cross-entropy to classify inputs into one of four categories.  Let's say live input `x_i` yields:

`[0 0.45 0.55 0]`

Let's also say you train a Naive Bayes classifier to categorize inputs, and for the same `x_i` input above, it gives you:

`[0.2 0.3 0.1 0.4]`

Averaging the results for the Neural Network and Naive Bayes classifiers, we get:

`[((0+0.2)/2) ((0.45+0.3)/2) ((0.55+0.1)/2) ((0+0.4)/2)]`

Which yields:

`[0.1 0.375 0.325 0.2]`

Using this ensemble approach, we classify the input `x_i` in the second category, whereas each method on their own predicts a different category.

Comment: Thanks redress! Combine output is a good idea, but i want to find the method that has the better result.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, then